# DocumentDb CreateDocumentQuery<T> to differentiate object types

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

I have a query statement that executes on partitioned collection:

```
     var q = this.DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<SomeFoo>(this.collectionUri, query, options).AsDocumentQuery();
```

Despite stating `SomeFoo` in the `CreateDocumentQuery<>` bit, the results ultimately just attempt to deserialize to that type, regardless of whether or not they ARE that type.

For example, if I have two classes:

1. SomeFoo: {Id, Name, Description, Location (PKEY)}
2. SomeBar: {Id, Title, Biography, Location (PKEY)}

And query with something like: `query = "select * from items where i.Location = 'New York'"`

I will receive a list of `SomeFoo` objects but several of the objects are actually `SomeBar` entities shoved into the envelope of a `SomeFoo` object. In other words, I'll see that the properties Description and Name are null in the `SomeFoo` object, but the id/location are present. I recognize the Id as an Id of a `SomeBar` object.

**How can I force the query to only return a specific object type without checking into random unrelated properties? Don't documents store their object type somewhere?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I've found is to simply make sure your documents have a DocType property that can be used for filtering.  Feels a bit off if you're used to relational db's, as your entities will be named as tables.  But that is the flexibility you get by going schema less. Your data store only knows about documents. Period. It is true that you can have different types of documents in most nosql db's, but the types don't map to your domain types.  They might be like JsonDocument or ImageDocument or similar. Ultimately just enforcing a field to track the type is pretty easy and doesn't get in the way much.  Something like:

```
public interface IDocumentModel
    {
        string Id { get; set; }
        string DocType { get; }
        DateTime CreatedOn {get; set;}
    }
```

Then you can query on the type all you want.  We use couchbase and the type field is also useful internally to help build indexes for various domain types.

Comment: If you want to support inheritance or mixins, you can also model it with `boolean IsBeer = true`, `boolean IsDomesticBeer = true` or `string[] Types = ["Beer", "DomesticBeer"]`

Answer (score -2):

That's why it's called "schemaless" DB. You can just store any valid JSON document. DocumentDB uses Json.NET behind scene for serialization/deserialization, you can force to include object type like that:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "something"", ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto, TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)]
public BaseSomething Something { get; set; }
```

JSON will look like that:

```
"$something": "MyLibrary.Entities.Foo, MyLibrary",
"something": ...,
```

Basically $[field] consists of object type then.

Comment: Well aware it's schema-less, but it's a rather un-captured or undocumented scenario:  "Here, make your own C# objects and throw them in, good luck deserializing them if they have even remotely similar properties when you want to get them out."

This is not about storing, it's about retrieving.